# Issue getting information to jade template with angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pug

I am working on a simple web app (new to it) and I am using jade/angular. I am trying to get a list to display some information, this is what I have:

layout.jade:

```
doctype
html(ng-app)
    head
        title= title
        script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/lib/angular.min.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/lib/angular-resource.min.js')
        script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='public/javascripts/app2.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet',type='text/css', href='/stylesheets/boostrap.css')
    body
        block content
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    div(class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl")
        h1 Angulair
        ul(ng-repeat="airport in airports") 
            li {{airport.code}}
            li {{airport.name}}
            li {{airport.destination}}
```

and finally app2.js:

```
function AppCtrl ($scope){
    $scope.airports = {
        "PDX": {
            "code": "PDX", 
            "name": "Portland", 
            "city": "Toronto"
        }
    }; 
}
```

EDIT: Everything below here is an edit...

I am working with node as well, this is what my project looks like

```
node_modules/
public/
    img/
    javascripts/
        app2.js
        stylesheets/(bootstrap files in here)
routes/
    index.js
views/
    partials/
    index.jade
    layout.jade
app.js
package.json
```

Also, I am using node for this project, In app.js I make a call to:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

index.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Angular Basic' });
};
```

As you can see, very simple stuff, but I cannot seem to get the list to display that airport information. Am I wrapping the jade template with angular correctly?

I CHANGED THE SCRIPTS IN layout.jade to include the angular resources. Now Nothing appears. I also added the brackets around the elements in the list tags, as suggested below. Still nothing appears.

Comment: Have you load angular library in your header?

Comment: That is the first script tag in layout.jade @Daiwei

Comment: I can only see `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tire0011 + Daiwei are both correct.

It's not your jade that is the problem. Here's a working sample incorporating tire0011 + Daiwei's suggestions:

http://plnkr.co/edit/q2DMGO0P50nWdf1PGlNJ?p=preview

Comment: I am using node.js as well with this project. In app.js I make a call to index.js, is there anyway that is screwing it up?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. Firstly I'd update the jade so that the html it generates is the same as the sample above and see if that works. If that's working you can then work backwards to how you want to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a app module name

```
doctype
html(ng-app="appName")
```

then in your script first create your module and then the controller

```
var myModule = angular.module('appName', []);

myModule.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) { 
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This still does not change anything. All it does is output: "airport.code", "airport.city", and "airport.name" in list format. It is not taking the information from that module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `li` tag, use `{{ XXX }}` to wrap your properties

```
li {{ airport.code }}
li {{ airport.city }}
li {{ airport.name }}
```